# UISegmentedControl Glow effect

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode, uisegmentedcontrol

Is it possible to add a **glow effect** in a `UISegmentedControl` like how its done in `UIbutton` using  `setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:YES`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The UISegmentControl is similar in that you can listen for events like UIControlEventTouchDown  & UIControlEventTouchUpInside so you could add your own glow layer on top of the segmentcontrol view to give it that effect.